# plotly.py layout images - hover events

Tags: javascript, python, image, plotly, hover

In plotly python, is it possible to trigger a hover event for images in your plot? I have a plot with a layout image. I would like to detect if the user hovers the mouse over the image.

example plot with image:

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[0, 0.5, 1, 2, 2.2], y=[1.23, 2.5, 0.42, 3, 1])
)

fig.add_layout_image(
        dict(
            source="https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png",
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            x=0,
            y=3,
            sizex=2,
            sizey=2,
            sizing="stretch",
            opacity=0.5,
            layer="below")
)

fig.show()
```

References:

• I've found hover events for plotly.js: https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-events/

• I see a hover example here: https://plotly.com/python/v3/cars-exploration/
but it does not work the way I intend, but perhaps it can be?

```
scatter = fig.data[0]

def hover_fn(trace, points, state):
    ind = points.point_inds[0]
    details.value = cars_df.iloc[ind].to_frame().to_html()

scatter.on_hover(hover_fn)
```

For instance, can I call something like:

```
def hover_fn():
   print("hello world")

my_image = fig.data[layout_image]
my_image.on_hover(hover_fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start out with code and explanation; at the end of this answer, I've added all of the code again in one chunk.

As far as I know, as long as it's a layout object, there is no simple method of instituting hover content. If you would like hover content, then instead of a layout object, make it a trace.

There is one major difference between images in the layout and images in a trace. In a trace, you have to encode the image to base64. When it's in the layout, Plotly does it for you. (Why?? GREAT QUESTION!!! I can tell you it's the same in other programming languages.)

The first step: encode the image for the trace.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

# read url
url = urlopen("https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png")
pref = "data:image/png;base64," # prefix for Javascript
# transcribe binary bytes into base64 UTF-8
aimg = pref + base64.b64encode((BytesIO(url.read())).getvalue()).decode('utf8')
```

When you add images as a trace, it automatically flips the y-axis. So, to prevent issues with the other trace, I have annotated a second y-axis.

```
fig = go.Figure().set_subplots(specs = [[{"secondary_y": True}]])
```

The traces. By the way, the order in which you code them is the order they are layered. So if you want the image on the bottom, add that trace first.

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[0, 0.5, 1, 2, 2.2], y=[1.23, 2.5, 0.42, 3, 1]),
    secondary_y = False
)
# size of image 100 x 100 with dx & dy at .03, reduce size to 3% of original
fig.add_trace(go.Image(source = aimg, x0 = 0, y0 = 0, dx = .03, dy = .03,
                       opacity = .5, hoverinfo = "all", zsmooth = 'fast',
                       name = "Python symbol"),
              secondary_y = True)
```

So that the image isn't skewed and the different axes are all aligned, I've added specifications for the axes to square it all up. I also hid the labels for the second y-axis.

```
fig.update_xaxes(range = [-.5, 3.5], constrain = "domain")
fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor = "x", scaleratio = 1, 
                 secondary_y = False, range = [-.5, 3.5])
fig.update_yaxes(title = "", secondary_y = True, scaleratio = 1, scaleanchor = "x", 
                 showticklabels = False, range = [3.5, -.5])
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

All the code altogether:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

# read url
url = urlopen("https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png")
pref = "data:image/png;base64," # prefix for Javascript
# transcribe binary bytes into base64 UTF-8
aimg = pref + base64.b64encode((BytesIO(url.read())).getvalue()).decode('utf8')

fig = go.Figure().set_subplots(specs = [[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[0, 0.5, 1, 2, 2.2], y=[1.23, 2.5, 0.42, 3, 1]),
    secondary_y = False
)

fig.add_trace(go.Image(source = aimg, x0 = 0, y0 = 0, dx = .03, dy = .03,
                       opacity = .5, hoverinfo = "all", zsmooth = 'fast',
                       name = "Python symbol"),
              secondary_y = True)


fig.update_xaxes(range = [-.5, 3.5], constrain = "domain")
fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor = "x", scaleratio = 1, 
                 secondary_y = False, range = [-.5, 3.5])
fig.update_yaxes(title = "", secondary_y = True, scaleratio = 1, scaleanchor = "x", 
                 showticklabels = False, range = [3.5, -.5])

fig.show()
```